# New marker on circle

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I searched on google alot. but, I couldnt find.

Can anyone tell me how to create (using onClick event) a new marker inside the bounds of a circle overlay.

```
var markerCenter = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        title: 'Location',
        map: map,
        draggable: false
    })
var c = {  
   strokeColor: "#ff0000",  
   strokeOpacity: 0.8,  
   strokeWeight: 3,  
   fillColor: false,  
   fillOpacity: 0.0,  
   map: map,  
   center: event.latLng,  
   radius: 4500,  
   editable:false  
};
circle = new google.maps.Circle(c);
circle.bindTo('center', markerCenter, 'position');
```

I am unable to create a new marker inside the circle bounds with onclick event.

Can anyone help me?

This is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/logan85001/wgjxb5wt/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare circle as global variable and

Change

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (e) {
```

To

```
google.maps.event.addListener(circle, "click", function (e) {
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vb9hsz7s/)